# delete rows in nested datatable

Tags: jsf-2, datatable, delete-row

im trying to delete a row in a nested datatable, but i get this message: Operation attempted on a deleted instance.

the row is deleted anyway, but the view get all messed up.. all the other rows under the one i deleted dissapear. i have to start the app all over again to see the changes properly.

this is the view:

```
  <h:dataTable var="father" value="#{miuchile3.getMenusPadre(miuchile3.keyModulo)}">
                                    <h:column>
                                        <li>
                                           <h:panelGroup rendered="#{father!=null}">
                                            <h:commandLink value="#{father.nombre}"
                                                           action="#{miuchile3.setMenu(father)}" rendered="#{father!=null}">
                                                <f:ajax render=":menupags:menuDetalle"/>
                                            </h:commandLink>
                                               </h:panelGroup>
                                            <ul>


                                                <h:dataTable var="submenu" value="#{miuchile3.getHijos(father.id)}" rendered="#{father!=null}">
                                                    <h:column>
                                                        <li><h:commandLink value="#{submenu.nombre}"
                                                                           action="#{miuchile3.setMenu(submenu)}">
                                                            <f:ajax render=":menupags:menuDetalle"/>

                                                        </h:commandLink></li>

                                                    </h:column>

                                                    <h:column>

                                                        <h:commandLink  value="Eliminar"
                                                                        action="#{miuchile3.DeleteMenu(submenu)}" >


                                                        </h:commandLink>
                                                    </h:column>

                                                </h:dataTable>


                                            </ul>


                                        </li>


                                    </h:column>
                                    <h:column>

                                        <h:commandLink  value="Eliminar"
                                                        action="#{miuchile3.DeleteMenu(father)}" >


                                        </h:commandLink>


                                       </h:column>
                                </h:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using  a4j:commandButton on delete function and then try to render the datatable